# Is it possible to render partial using link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, render, partial, link-to

I have a Rails 3 application with simple navigation that contains links to controllers actions using link_to helper.

Now, I need to add a link which will refer to partial. Is it possible to combine the link_to and render: partial methods?

Generally, what I need is to combine somehow the following codes and have a link_to which is rendering the partial:

```
<%= link_to 'List', security_users_path , remote:true, class:'e-icon e-icon-camera' %>

<% @security_user = SecurityUser.new %>
<%= render partial: 'security_users/sign_in', :locals => {:security_user => @security_user} %>
```

If it is not possible, what other alternatives I have if I want to render a partial?